# ec2 instance connect endpoint: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, vpc-endpoint, aws-ec2-instance-connect

I am following this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/connect-using-eice.html) and I try to ssh to the private ec2. I have created the ec2 connect endpoint and I am able to use to connect from the console.

When using ssh from my mac terminal, I have below message:

```
ssh -i <key-pair>.pem ec2-user@i-xxxxxxx -o ProxyCommand='aws ec2-instance-connect open-tunnel --instance-id i-xxxxxxx'

usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

send-ssh-public-key                      | send-serial-console-ssh-public-key      
help                                    

kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
```

Below is the version of the aws cli I am using:

```
aws --version
aws-cli/2.11.27 Python/3.11.3 Darwin/22.5.0 exe/x86_64 prompt/off
```

My vpc endpoint connect endpoint:

[image: ec2 instance connect endpoint]

How to fixe the ssh connection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new EC2 Instance Connect Endpoint feature will be added to AWS CLI v2 once the version 2.12.0 is released, referring to [the official change log](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/aws-cli/v2/CHANGELOG.rst). I expect the repositories will be updated very soon with the latest version of the AWS CLI.

Edit: it is available now. I tested with my EC2s and it is perfectly working. If you are having the same issue, you just need to update your AWS CLI to the latest version.

Comment: I confirm it works now after updating the aws cli to the latest one. Thanks